# Simple algebraic manipulation with 2 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

My first equations is this: $ d_2 = d - 30.$

My second equations is  this: ${1\over d_2 }= {1\over12} - {1\over1.066(d-30)}$

I am trying to solve for $d_2$ in the second equation and then set the two equations equal to each other to solve for d.

I am having trouble solving for $d_2$ in the second equation. I think the fractions are giving me a hard time. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{d_{2}}=\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{1.066d_{2}} $$

$$(1+\frac{1}{1.066})\frac{1}{d_{2}}=\frac{1}{12}$$

$$d_{2}=12(1+\frac{1}{1.066})$$

$$d=d_{2}+30$$

$$d=12(1+\frac{1}{1.066})+30$$

Answer (score 1):

First, I hate decimals, so let's note that 1.066 equals $\frac{533}{500}$.

Then, since we were essentially given what $d_2$ equals, let's substitute that into our second equation like so:

$$ \frac{1}{d-30} = \frac{1}{12} - \frac{1}{\frac{533}{500}(d-30)}$$
$$ \frac{1}{d-30} = \frac{1}{12} - \frac{500}{533(d-30)}$$

Now we want to multiply through by the LCM (which in our case is simply $12 \cdot 533(d-3)$) $6396(d-30)$ to obtain:

$$ 6396 = 533(d-30) - 6000 $$

Now we have a nice linear equation which we may solve for $d$:

$$ 533d - 21990 = 6396 $$
$$ d = \frac{28386}{533} $$

With $d$ obtained we can easily find $d_2$:

$$ d_2 = d - 30$$
$$ d_2 = \frac{28386}{533} - 30 $$
$$ d_2 = \frac{12396}{533} $$

And we're done.